# Result is orderd by other sql querys result

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem running my code. The code does order by the datetime from the database but it's still in the order of the id's of the follower database. I want to order all the messages by datetime and not order by following and than datetime... Hope you can help me!

query for the followers:

```
  $sqlselector = "SELECT * FROM isFollowing WHERE follower=?;";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlselector)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
}
else {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $resultget = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  $resultselector = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
  while($selector = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultget)) {
```

query for the messages:

```
 $sqlmeessages = "SELECT * FROM meessages WHERE idUser=? ORDER BY `meessages`.`timePosted` ASC LIMIT 200;";
      $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
      if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlmeessages)) {
          header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
      }
      else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $selector['isFollowing']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $resultmeessages = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      }
      //while loop for the meessages
      while($rowmeessages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultmeessages)) {
```

I expect to the result to be that the messages are orderd by only the date time and not the id's from the other database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're running one *unordered* query and then running *multiple* ordered queries.  The overall loop is still running over the unordered query.  But more to the point, you don't need to execute many queries to return a single set of data.  The `JOIN` keyword allows you to join your tables into a single result set.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM isFollowing
INNER JOIN messages ON isFollowing.follower = messages.idUser
WHERE isFollowing.follower = ?
ORDER BY messages.timePosted ASC
LIMIT 200
```

(You might even be more explicit about the columns than `SELECT *`, particularly if there are any column names used in both tables.)

This is really just scratching the surface of what a **S**tructured **Q**uery **L**anguage can do to query relational data.  And as a general rule of thumb it's almost *always* better to let SQL handle the optimization of querying and structuring the data rather than (it's *really* good at that) than to issue many simple queries and piece it all together in application code.

Comment: Yes this does work, the only problem is that the query shows the same message a multiple times... Take a look: https://meessages.nl/

Comment: @MeesEgberts: Without a better understanding of your data there isn't much I can suggest other than to generally account for your data structure in your application logic.  What is your data?  What is the output you're seeing?  What is the output you expect to see?

Comment: I think its with the while loop... The output is the last 200 messages and than the same 200 messages again and again and again! Hope you have a better understanding now!

Comment: @MeesEgberts: No, that doesn't provide any examples of your data, how it's structured, or the output you're seeing or expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just do this with a single query?  It is hard to follow your data structures, but something like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM isFollowing f JOIN
     messages m
     ON m.idUser = f.follower
WHERE f.follower = ?
ORDER BY m.TimePosted;
```